# Can we make Pebble Watch to transmit over bluetooth, and use it as bluetooth advertisement?

Tags: bluetooth, pebble-watch

I was thinking can we make Pebble watch to transmit signal strength over bluetooth and use it as a bluetooth advertisement device. This way Pebble itself can be used to do something that we have iBeacons doing.

Any thought about it?

Comment: Likely the hardware is capable of sending a BLE advertisement, so the manufacturers of the pebble watch probably could; if you could would depend if it is possible for a 3rd party to load software which alters the radio operating modes.  It appears this has not been the case http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/comment/90546/#Comment_90546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Pebble does not provide any Bluetooth LE APIs (as of march 2014).

iBeacon is a Bluetooth LE based protocol. You will have to wait for Pebble Bluetooth LE apis to do that.